# Error creating record with dasherized name of model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model called `AdGroup` which is being declared like this:

```
App.AdGroup = DS.Model.extend({ ... });
```

I'm trying to create a record using `this.store.createRecord('ad-group')` but Ember throws the error `No model was found for 'ad'`.

Changing it to `createRecord('adgroup')` or `createRecord('adGroup')` throws similar errors.

When I check the Ember console data tab, the model shows up dasherized as `ad-group` so I'm not sure what I'm meant to be setting it as. I know I could just declare the model as `App.Adgroup` but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Which adapter are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use ad-group. Sounds like there's something else going on. What does the model definition look like?

Take a look at [this working example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qadam/4/edit) at JSBin.com.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put together that example. Looking through it I realised I had made a reference to `adGroup` (non-dasherized) in a model relationship, and that caused the error. I wish Ember would be more verbose about what's wrong sometimes!